# Overwrite built-in function

Tags: python, function, built-in

I have a large chunk of code which uses the "print" statement. As to say in this way:

```
print "foo"
```

and not

```
print("foo")
```

I want to alter the output. Can I do this without changing all the lines with print? For example by overwriting the function/statement?

Comment: Are you trying to make your code compatible for python 3?

Comment: What do you mean by `alter the output`?

Comment: If this is for conversion to Python3, the [2to3](http://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) tool will take care of this automatically.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This changes the behavior of the `print` statement without forcing you to change

`print "foo"`

to

```
print("foo")
```

---

```
import sys
_stdout = sys.stdout

class MyStream(object):
    def __init__(self, target):
        self.target = target

    def write(self, s):
        s = 'Foo : {!r}'.format(s)
        self.target.write(s)
sys.stdout = MyStream(sys.stdout)
print 'Hi'
sys.stdout = _stdout   # return print to its old behavior
```

yields

```
Foo : 'Hi'
```

This could be neatened with a context manager, but if you don't want to change your `print` statements into `print` functions, you probably don't want to have to wrap your `print` statements in a context manager either.

---

So, a better, a more civilized way would be to use

```
2to3 --write  --fix print test.py
```

to automatically change all the `print` statements in your code (e.g. test.py above) into `print` functions. Then you can change the behaviour by redefining the `print` function:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import __builtin__

def print(*args, **kwargs): 
    __builtin__.print('Foo:', *args, **kwargs)
print('Hi')
```

yields

```
Foo: Hi
```

Answer (score 15):

Python **directly** supports what you want to do:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Any module with that line at the top will treat the `print` statement as a function instead, making the code compatible with both Python 2 and 3.

This applies **just** to the `print` statement; you cannot override other statements.

This does mean you then have to use `print()` as a function everywhere in that module, but you can then also provide your own implementation if you so desire:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import __builtin__

def print(*args, **kwargs):
    __builtin__.print('Prefixed:', *args, **kwargs)

print('Hello world!')
```

Another option is to use a context manager to capture printed statements, directing the output away from `sys.stdout` into a in-memory file object of your choosing:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import sys
try:
    from cStringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from StringIO import StringIO


@contextmanager
def capture_sys_output():
    caputure_out = StringIO()
    current_out = sys.stdout
    try:
        sys.stdout = caputure_out
        yield caputure_out
    finally:
        sys.stdout = current_out
```

and wrap any blocks that you want to capture `print` output for with the context manager. Here is an example prefixing printed lines:

```
with capture_sys_output as output:
    print 'Hello world!'

output = output.get_value()
for line in output.splitlines():
    print 'Prefixed:', line
```

or even provide a wrapper:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import sys

class Prefixer(object):
    def __init__(self, prefix, orig):
        self.prefix = prefix
        self.orig = orig
    def write(self, text):
        self.orig.write(self.prefix + text)
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.orig, attr)     

@contextmanager
def prefix_stdout(prefix):
    current_out = sys.stdout
    try:
        sys.stdout = Prefixer(prefix, current_out)
        yield
    finally:
        sys.stdout = current_out
```

and use as:

```
with prefix_stdout('Prefixed: '):
    print 'Hello world!'
```

but take into account that `print` statements usually write data to `stdout` in separate chunks; the newline at the end is a *separate* write.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: Yes it is, really.

Comment: Ahh, and then he can go ahead and overwrite the builtin. I'd still prefer switching sys.stdout, but who knows.

Comment: The problem is that in that case, he has to change all his print statements to use parens, and changing all his print statements is exactly what he's trying to avoid.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: But it'll be much easier to maintain than using a global 'swap out `stdout`' hammer.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich, it's better to be explicit, and use the print function (and make a one-time effort of replacing the code), than face implicit consequences of changes global variables.

Comment: If he's already changing all the print()s, he can also change them to call his_own_custom_print() instead and doesn't need to overwrite anything, but he's asking how to avoid doing that work.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich, perhaps it could take more effort and time to do what the OP wants, fixing the side-effects on code called by the mentioned code, than replacing the strings and be on the safe side.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: you can name the override `print()` too..

Comment: Context manager decorator... I like it!

Answer (score 4):

In Python 2.x, `print` is a statement and so it can be called without parens. Apparently you're using that.

You can't overwrite the built-in print statement.

However, it writes its output to `sys.stdout`. Perhaps you can overwrite sys.stdout with some object that has a .write method, like this:

```
import sys
from StringIO import StringIO

s = StringIO()
sys.stdout = s

print "Hmmm."

assert s.getvalue() == "Hmmm.\n"
```

Comment: Actually, you **can**. *Just* the `print` statement, mind you, but you can.

Comment: Note that this will also alter _all_ stdout operations done by the code _called_ by that large chunk of code OP mentioned. This is not isolated only to the mentioned code's scope.

Answer (score 3):

In Python 2, there is the print *statement*, which is a language construct. As such, you won’t be able to overwrite its behavior.

In Python 3, and in Python 2 if you enable it explicitely, you have the print *function*. It does require the parentheses, so `print "foo"` will not work, but you can redefine what it does:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function # for Python 2
>>> oldPrintFunction = print
>>> def print (*args, **kwargs):
        oldPrintFunction('I am a changed print function')
        oldPrintFunction(*args, **kwargs)

>>> print('foo')
I am a changed print function
foo
```

Comment: PERFECT! Exactly what I wanted to do! Thank you.